# How to get the textarea value from jQuery LineControl Editor?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this [jquery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor.html)  to create a wysiwyg text editor,
I created a textarea where I want to display the text editor:

```
<textarea class="editor" rows="3" name="textEditor" id="textEditor"></textarea>
```

and then I called the jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#textEditor").Editor();                   
  });
</script>
```

Until now everything is working good, but when I wanted to know if the text is writed correctly or not by using this function:

```
function displayText(){
  alert($("#textEditor").val());
}
```

it gives me an empty text!
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation of that plugin on Github](https://github.com/suyati/line-control), you need to use the `getText` option to retrieve the value of the editor. Try this:

```
function displayText(){
    alert($("#textEditor").Editor("getText"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right!!!

There two methods to get and set text.

```
 $("#TextEditorID").Editor("setText", "TextInput")); 
 $("#TextEditorID").Editor("getText));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayText() {
        alert($('#txtEditor').text($('#txtEditor').Editor("getText"))[0].value);
    }
```

Comment: Always try to explain your answers so that the readers would understand it better